# Is there a way I can Download images from any search engine with a code like this?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, bytesio

I tried downloading images from bing to a directory but due to some reason the code just executes and gives me nothing.. not even an error.. I used the user-agent HTTP as well.. but it still doesnt seem to be working.. What should i do?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

url = 'https://www.bing.com/search'
search = input("Search for: ")
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 
Firefox/80.0'}
params = {"q": search}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
links = soup.findAll("a", {"class": "thumb"})

for item in links:
     img_obj = requests.get(item.attrs["href"])
     print("Getting", item.attrs["href"])
     title = item.attrs["href"].split("/")[-1]
     img = Image.open(BytesIO(img_obj.content))
     img.save("./scraped_images/" + title, img.format)
```

Comment: I see no `<a>` tags with class `thumb` when I search for e.g. `"tree"`. Is that correct?

Comment: Ok i see the a with class="iusc".. do you see the same? i even put iusc now and it still isn't working.. is there something wrong within the for loop.. i mean in the results.get inside the for loop? Am I supposed to put header there as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all images, you need to add `/images` to the link. Here's an example with modifications to your code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import requests
import json

search = input("Search for: ")

url = "https://www.bing.com/images/search"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0"
}
params = {"q": search, "form": "HDRSC2", "first": "1", "scenario": "ImageBasicHover"}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
links = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "img_cont hoff"})

for data in soup.find_all("a", {"class": "iusc"}):
    json_data = json.loads(data["m"])
    img_link = json_data["murl"]
    img_object = requests.get(img_link, headers=headers)
    title = img_link.split("/")[-1]

    print("Getting: ", img_link)
    print("Title: ", title + "\n")

    img = Image.open(BytesIO(img_object.content))
    img.save("./scraped_images/" + title)
```

Comment: @SanskarB.C. Please consider marking the answer as accepted

Comment: @SanskarB.C. See [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: ya Thanks man.. but apart from the missing /images .. My code was just as fine.. it was still showing some errors tho.. why did you use Json at the later parts? and what wrong was there with my code?

Comment: @SanskarB.C. I don't remember what exactly happened. But the links to the images were in JSON format. So I extracted it using the `json` module.

Comment: Lastly .. whats the m in data["m"] and murl  just below that?

Comment: @SanskarB.C. First, `json.loads` converts the data to a dictionary. By `m` we're getting a value from `data` - see https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp. Also try adding `print() ` statements and see what's happening. I Hope this clear!

Comment: @MendelG, Do you have any suggestions to download the next pages of the search?